# MSmerge_contents error when synching Merge Replication subscriber following reinitialize (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm getting the following error when trying to synch up a subscriber after setting the subscription to Reinitialize.

> The process could not bulk copy into table "dbo"."MSmerge_contents".
>   Field size too large.

Other subscribers to the publication are still working fine, and all snapshots are current. With MSmerge_contents being a system table this error message doesn't seem to make much sense. I've went as far as dropping and recreating the subscription and deleted all tables from the subscription database to assure they are getting fully recreated from scratch. The subscriber I'm testing with is a separate database on the same server as as the publication db so I don't think there are any network connectivity or security problems.

I several other references to this problem on other forums, but no solutions. Anybody got any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be if the schema didn't match between the publisher and the subscriber.  Specifically, the column widths.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, which was why I dropped the subscription and all tables and recreated everything from scratch as described. Any other thoughts, or anyone else ever seen this?